# pandas: count things

Tags: python, pandas

In the following, male_trips is a big pandas data frame and stations is a small pandas data frame. For each station id I'd like to know how many male trips took place. The following does the job, but takes a long time:

```
mc = [ sum( male_trips['start_station_id'] == id ) for id in stations['id'] ]
```

how should I go about this instead?

---

Update! So there were two main approaches: `groupby()` followed by `size()`, and the simpler `.value_counts()`. I did a quick `timeit`, and the `groupby` approach wins by quite a large margin! Here is the code:

```
from timeit import Timer
setup = "import pandas; male_trips=pandas.load('maletrips')"
a  = "male_trips.start_station_id.value_counts()"
b = "male_trips.groupby('start_station_id').size()"
Timer(a,setup).timeit(100)
Timer(b,setup).timeit(100)
```

and here is the result:

```
In [4]: Timer(a,setup).timeit(100) # <- this is value_counts
Out[4]: 9.709594964981079

In [5]: Timer(b,setup).timeit(100) # <- this is groupby / size
Out[5]: 1.5574288368225098
```

Note that, at this speed, for exploring data *typing* value_counts is marginally quicker and less remembering!

Comment: How big is the data frame? Do you have enough memory? I don't see anything wrong with it speed wise.

Comment: @myusuf3 just for comparison, my approach above takes more than a minute (I got bored counting) whereas Dani's solution below would be measured in ms.

Comment: This is really surprising since there is a specific value count function in algorithms.py and I doubt Wes would have added this if it wasn't faster than groupby and then size. I get different results for a DataFrame I just loaded : In [20]: timeit df.groupby(df.columns[8]).size() 100 loops, best of 3: 13.4 ms per loop In [22]: timeit df[df.columns[8]].value_counts() 100 loops, best of 3: 5.62 ms per loop.

Comment: Be sure to run timing tests multiple times (10 or more) and in multiple orders (a before b, a after b).  If you only did two tests, it is possible the first run loaded the data from disk into a disk buffer, and the second run read it directly from the buffer, avoiding the disk access time.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I'd do like Vishal but instead of using sum() using size() to get a count of the number of rows allocated to each group of 'start_station_id'. So:

```
df = male_trips.groupby('start_station_id').size()
```

Comment: You solution is the same of `male_trips.value_counts('start_station_id')`

Answer (score 21):

My answer below works in Pandas 0.7.3. Not sure about the new releases.

This is what the `pandas.Series.value_counts` method is for:

```
count_series = male_trips.start_station_id.value_counts()
```

It should be straight-forward to then inspect `count_series` based on the values in `stations['id']`. However, if you insist on *only* considering those values, you could do the following:

```
count_series = (
                male_trips[male_trips.start_station_id.isin(stations.id.values)]
                    .start_station_id
                    .value_counts()
               )
```

and this will only give counts for station IDs actually found in `stations.id`.

Answer (score 3):

```
male_trips.count()
```

doesnt work?
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.count.html

Comment: .count() seems to count all the non-null values in each column which is cool, just not quite what I'm after.

Answer (score 3):

how long would this take:

```
df = male_trips.groupby('start_station_id').sum()
```

Comment: .sum() adds up the numeric columns in the db. Nearly does the job, though!

Answer (score 2):

edit: after seeing in the answer above that `isin` and `value_counts` exist (and `value_counts` even comes with its own entry in `pandas.core.algorithm` and also `isin` isn't simply `np.in1d`) I updated the three methods below

```
male_trips.start_station_id[male_trips.start_station_id.isin(station.id)].value_counts()
```

You could also do an inner join on stations.id:
`pd.merge(male_trips, station, left_on='start_station_id', right_on='id')` followed by `value_counts`.
Or:

```
male_trips.set_index('start_station_id, inplace=True)
station.set_index('id, inplace=True)
male_trips.ix[male_trips.index.intersection(station.index)].reset_index().start_station_id.value_counts()
```

If you have the time I'd be interested how this performs differently with a huge DataFrame.

Comment: cool. So male_trips.start_station_id[male_trips.start_station_id.isin(stations.id)].value_counts() does the trick, though is maybe a heartbeat slower than groupby.

Comment: the merge complains that there's 'no item named start_station_id'. This approach is one of the ones I'd been trying to get work and was bumping into this problem a lot. Not quite sure what's going on here...

Comment: the reindexing also complains, and I'm definitely not sure what's going on here. Here's the error: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects.

Comment: incidentally you have just shown me 5 completely new pandas concepts. Thanks!

Comment: It was my bad:  "on" is only to be used when the columns occur in both DataFrames (so my code was referring to a join on both id and start_station_id which is wrong here). Here you have to use "left_on" and "right_on".   For the reindex: non-unique indices are rather new in pandas. It could be that this isn't supported. Try df.ix[...] instead of df.reindex which doesn't throw this error.

Comment: I filed an issue because of the reindex error:  https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2067